# Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces

Tags: python

I'm getting the error "inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation" but as far as I can tell everything is as it should be. Specifically it refers to the `for item in poly(1:):` and it has an up carrot below the last colon. I'm using Notepad++ editor and Python 3.4. Any thoughts?

```
def compute_deriv(poly):
    new_poly = ()
    for item in poly(1:):
        new_poly.append(poly.index(item)*item)
    return new_poly

print(compute_deriv(-13.89,0.0,17.5,3.0,1.0))
```

Comment: what's the *first* error message?

Comment: view->show symbol->show whitespace and TAB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating a list at all and are slicing incorrectly:

```
new_poly = [] # now it's a list
for item in poly[1:]: # poly[1:] not poly(1:)
```

Your syntax is completely invalid, tabs and spaces are not the cause of that. You also cannot append to a tuple, you append to a list.

I would also use enumerate to get the indexes unless you only want the first index for repeated elements:

```
def compute_deriv(poly):
    new_poly = []
    for ind , item in enumerate(poly[1:],1):
        new_poly.append(ind*item)
    return new_poly
```

If you want a tuple then you should know tuples have no append and they  are **immutable** so you would have to create a new tuple every iteration or simply use a list and return `tuple(new_poly)`.

You also pass no  sliceable object when you call the function, instead you pass 5 args to a function that takes 1.

If you really want a tuple just use a gen exp and call tuple in it:

```
def compute_deriv(poly):
    return tuple(ind*item for ind, item in enumerate(poly[1:]))
```

Call it passing a tuple of items:

```
 print(compute_deriv((-13.89,0.0,17.5,3.0,1.0)))
```

Output:

```
(0.0, 17.5, 6.0, 3.0)
```

Comment: but i dont want to create a list, i want to create a tuple.

Comment: The given code in the question should pop a `SyntaxError`, not something involving tabs/spaces. It's possible that something else is amiss as well.

Comment: @futevolei how are you going to append to a tuple?

Comment: You'll need to investigate the differences between a `list` and a `tuple`, and how to create each one (I recommend the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial)).

Comment: oh man, im getting clowned here!  my fault guys, serious rookie mistakes!